# How do I use Pygal to make a visualization for a random walk?

Tags: python

I've been working on this exercise in Python Crash Course (exercise 15.10) where I need to visualize a random walk using Pygal. The final graph should look like a histogram. After being unable to figure it out on my own, I searched around for the solution and pieced what I could find into the code below. However, the code doesn't work and has errors such as "RandomWalk element has no attribute "fill_walk"". I thought it does have this attribute since I imported random_walk into random_walk_visulization. Can someone please help me in creating this graph. Thanks!

random_walk.py

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk():
"A class to regerate random walks"
def __init__(self, num_points = 5000):
        self.num_points= num_points

    #All walks start at (0,0)
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

def fill_walk(self):
        while len(self.x_values)  < self.num_points:
            x_direction = choice([1,-1])
            x_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
            x_step = x_direction * x_distance

            y_direction = choice([1,-1])
            y_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
            y_step = y_direction * y_distance

            #Reject steps that go nowhere
            if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
                continue


            #Calculate the next x and y values
            next_x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step
            next_y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

            #Append/add on the next_x and y values to self.x and y values
            self.x_values.append(next_x)
            self.y_values.append(next_y)
```

random_walk_visualization

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pygal
from random_walk import RandomWalk

# Make a random walk, and plot the points.
rw = RandomWalk()
rw.fill_walk()

# Visualize the rw with pygal.
scat = pygal.XY(stroke=False)

scat.add('rw', list(zip(rw.x_values, rw.y_values)))

scat.render_to_file('rw_visual.svg')

# Set the size of the plotting window
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

point_numbers = list(range(rw.num_points))
plt.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values, c=point_numbers, cmap=plt.cm.copper,
            edgecolor='none', s=2)

# emphasize the first and last points.
plt.scatter(0, 0, c='green', edgecolor='none', s=100)
plt.scatter(rw.x_values[-1], rw.y_values[-1], c='red', edgecolors='none',
            s=100)

# Remove the axes.
plt.axes().get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.axes().get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This looks like it might be a simple indentation issue. Everything under the definition of `class RandomWalk():` should be indented one level. Without indentation, `__init__()` and `fill_walk()` are just functions in the `random_walk.py` module, they're not actually part of the `RandomWalk` class.

Comment: I fixed the intention errors and even got rid of the plt.scatter() to make sure the visual displayed is a bar graph and it still doesn't work.

Comment: "It still doesn't work" doesn't really let anyone offer you any help. What error message do you get now? Post the full error message, not just a summary of the error. Also, have you generated a simple scatter plot with pygal before trying the random walk example?